TypeError int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
I started learning devops, and have this small app on AWS that basically just checks connections to rds and redis. But redis doesn't get settings such as port, host etc. At first I put the variables into ci.yml, it didnt work. Then I tried docker-compose with .env file and got same results. Kind of lost right now as have no other ideas how to fix it. The code is correct, because it was provided to me by more experienced friends.
the issue is with redis variables, both $REDIS_PORT and $REDIS_HOST. Logs: Request Method: GET Request URL: 13.53.189.243:8001/test_connection File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1415, in get_connection connection = self._available_connections.pop() Exception Type: TypeError at /test_connection/ Exception Value: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType
The issue is that no variables are sent to redis, when I used docker exec -it backend_redis_container env | grep REDIS command, I see all the variables, but when connecting have the following error:
TypeError at /test_connection/ int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType

settings.py

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend_redis.urls'
ROOT_HOSTCONF = 'backend_redis.hosts'
DEFAULT_HOST = 'default'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend_redis.wsgi.application'

# Redis settings
REDIS_HOST = os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST')
REDIS_PORT = os.environ.get('REDIS_PORT')
REDIS_DB = os.environ.get('REDIS_DB')
REDIS_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('REDIS_PASSWORD')
# Database
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


As it's getting a NoneType, probably it's expecting another variable that you're not filling. How are you initiating the Redis pool?
Also, you're not setting the cache backend, as in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/cache/#redis

So you have a Django app that is throwing an error because it doesn't have REDIS_HOST or REDIS_PORT environment variables defined. You are checking for those variables in the backend_redis_container docker container. Is that container the one that is actually running your Django application?

Yes, im using docker container to run the application. What do you mean variables are undefined, how i can fix it?

os.environ.get() returns None if the given variable is not found in the environment, so REDIS_PORT ends up with a null value (and likely all those other variables too).

NoneType means that the env variables aren't defined, and if you’re not seeing the environment variables also, it means you need to ensure they are properly set. Here’s how to do it depending on your setup:

Using docker-compose

Make sure your docker-compose.yml includes the following:
env_file:
  - .env

and the .env file content should have :
REDIS_HOST=your_redis_host
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_DB=0
REDIS_PASSWORD=your_password


Running Directly with docker

If you’re running your container directly with docker, you need to pass the environment variables like this:
docker run -e REDIS_HOST=your_redis_host \
           -e REDIS_PORT=6379 \
           -e REDIS_DB=0 \
           -e REDIS_PASSWORD=your_password \
           your_django_image

that's the thing. then if you apply any of the previous solution this command
docker exec -it backend_redis_container env | grep REDIS

will list for you the REDIS variables.
you can get all these variable from the redis setting and configuration, and make sure that you didn't disable Password authentication for the REDIS, otherwise you'll only be able to access it using IAM instead.
